# What is the difference between Name and FullName in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, properties

In my code I am writing a formula which refers to a workbook I previously defined. I was wondering if there is a difference between the Name and FullName property? The Microsoft website doesn't seem to make the distinction between the two clear.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Name` will return the name of a file (ex: `workbook.xlsx`)

`FullName` will return the path *and* name of a file (ex: `c:\myDocuments\workbook.xlsx`)

`Path` will return the path of a file (ex: `c:\myDocuments`)

Comment: Can you explain to me when I would want the file path instead of just the name?

Comment: You may want the `Path` in order to save or open other files in the same directory.

Answer (score 2):

You can quickly check in the Immediate Window (in the VBEditor, press <kbd>CTRL+G</kbd>) and type:

```
?Thisworkbook.Name
2019 Workbook Test.xlsm
?thisworkbook.FullName
K:\Excel Files\Primary Data\2019 Workbook Test.xlsm
```

Answer (score 0):

Full name includes the file path.

Comment: @avariant The question asks how the `Name` and `FullName` properties differ; this answer attempts to explain.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware, if the workbook hasn't yet been saved, both `.Name` and `.FullName` will only return `"Book1"` or similar. It's not until the workbook's been saved that they'll have complete data, such as `"Book1.xlsm"` or `"C:\path...\Documents\Book1.xlsm"`.

Also, if you use `ThisWorkbook.Name` or `ThisWorkbook.Fullname`, they'll point to the workbook where your code is. For instance, if the code is in a workbook in your `Documents` folder, they'll be as stated above. But if you're working on code in your Personal Macro Workbook, they'll say `Personal.xlsb` and `C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLStart\Personal.xlsb` (or similar).